# Extjs: Add Link to container

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to create a specialized class which should contain, among other things, a link and a image.

I have something like:

```
Ext.define('Macros.app.ribbonAction', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    //extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.ribbonAction',

    initComponent: function () {
        Ext.apply(this, {                
                items:[
                    {}
                    ]
            }
        );
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

What's the best way to add a link (bound to a javascript function) to the items collection?
The closest I can find is a button, but I'd really prefer a good old-fashioned link.

(I'm using ExtJs 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about standard box?

```
{ 
    xtype: 'box',
    id: 'myLinkId',
    autoEl: '<a href="#">Link</a>'
}
```

And add this to the container.

The only problem is that you need to assign event handler for 'click' event and you can do this only after element has been rendered.

Comment: hmm.. Looks good, but it doesn't render anything when I add that to the items collection.

Comment: Well, your container is actually a component. Why don't you change it to container?

Comment: Ah! That's a good pointer. I'm still trying to get on top of all the containers, components etc.. I think I'm going to have to read up on this a bit :)